# PLSQL: mutating table stopping my 'before update trigger'. What to do?

Tags: plsql, triggers, mutating-table

I've finally compiled my trigger , but now I'm getting a mutating table error when I do the relevant update:

```
ORA-04091: table KEV.STORE_COPY is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "KEV.SOLD", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'KEV.SOLD'
```

I know that you can fix this problem by removing the line 'for each row' in your trigger, but I need to use my 'old' and 'new' values so I need the 'for each row' code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SOLD
BEFORE UPDATE OF STATUS ON STORE_COPY
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
RENT_OR_SALE NVARCHAR2(6);
UPDATED_DVD_ID NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
SELECT (SELECT DVD_ID FROM STORE_COPY WHERE :NEW.STATUS != :OLD.STATUS) INTO      UPDATED_DVD_ID FROM DUAL;
SELECT (SELECT RENT_OR_SALE FROM DVD JOIN STORE_COPY ON STORE_COPY.DVD_ID = DVD.DVD_ID  WHERE DVD.DVD_ID = UPDATED_DVD_ID) INTO RENT_OR_SALE FROM DUAL;
IF :NEW.STATUS != :OLD.STATUS
THEN
IF :OLD.STATUS = 'Y'
THEN
IF :NEW.STATUS = 'N'
THEN
IF RENT_OR_SALE = 'S'
THEN
INSERT INTO SOLD VALUES(NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, (SELECT PRICE FROM DVD JOIN STORE_COPY  ON STORE_COPY.DVD_ID = DVD.DVD_ID WHERE :NEW.DVD_ID = UPDATED_DVD_ID), :NEW.DVD_ID);
END IF;
END IF;
END IF;
END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to reference STORE_COPY in these two SELECTS :

```
SELECT (SELECT DVD_ID FROM STORE_COPY WHERE :NEW.STATUS != :OLD.STATUS) INTO      UPDATED_DVD_ID FROM DUAL;
SELECT (SELECT RENT_OR_SALE FROM DVD JOIN STORE_COPY ON STORE_COPY.DVD_ID = DVD.DVD_ID  WHERE DVD.DVD_ID = UPDATED_DVD_ID) INTO RENT_OR_SALE FROM DUAL;
```

The first SELECT is just plain wrong. I don't know what you are trying to do, but that SQL will either return 0 rows or all rows and attempt to put that into a scalar value.

It looks like you have the same problem in the second SELECT (and also in the INSERT).

Just use the DVD_ID from NEW or OLD instead of trying to select it from STORE_COPY.

Comment: Would dvd_id (old or new) just return the modified row? That's what I was trying to ensure in my round about way.

Comment: `:OLD` is the row in STORE_COPY as it looks before the update. `:NEW` is how it will look after the update.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger can't select from a table it's fired for. Otherwise you'll get ORA-04091: table XXXX is mutating, trigger/function may not see it. try not to put too much logic into triggers.

anyway, I knew that it possible to do a round solution but honestly I didn't try it..., what I know that you can Create Stored procedure, create a job and run the job from the trigger.

Comment: Replaced all my triggers with a handful of procedures.Worth it.